# Method to convert android logs to events

Tags: android, logging, complex-event-processing

How to convert android logs to events in order to do complex event processing? 
Please suggest hints or methods.

Comment: you cannot convert the logs to events. But , you can parse the logcat output and look for the specific events and do necessary action. The logcat output can be extensive , so you would have to add necessary filtering to achieve the result. what is your usecase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a previous oracle Event Processing experience, If you can read the logs, then you can trasform them to events, using adapters or custom Java code. Hope the same for your CEP platform.

> An Oracle Event Processing application receives and processes data streaming from an event source. That data might be coming from one of a variety of places, such as a monitoring device, a financial services company, or a motor vehicle.

More here: [Getting Started with Oracle Event Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/eventprocessing/CEPGS/GUID-93619B1F-0B17-472E-8B01-CBA9C6FE6D32.htm#CEPGS-GUID-E0F4DE58-E7F1-4F43-9E5C-71CD5D35E617)

Comment: This is a generic CEP system. So, can this method be used to transform unstructured logs to events?

Comment: Events will be represented as Java Objects, so they have to be structured, but may be you can find some workaround.